# Importing a css npm package in css file

Tags: css, npm, npm-package

I made a NPM package which contains a CSS file which I have to include in my main CSS file.
In a normal html CSS website I have to write **@import url("./node_modules/web-creative-fonts/index.css")** but what I want to do is that we just have to write **@import "web-creative-fonts"** .
I studied a bit about it and found that we can make a webpack.config.js to do it ,but I am not able to figure out how.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use something like [css-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader). It's a Webpack plugin that makes importing CSS from NPM a breeze.